# How to set userid for products added to cart in magento?

Tags: cart, configurable-product, addtocart, customer-session

I am adding configurable products in to cart using the below code.

```
$product_id = 123; 
$qty        = 1; 
$product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$cart       = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart'); 
$cart->init();

$superAttributeArray = array('151' => '3');

$params = array(
        'product' => $product_id,
        'qty'     => $qty,
        'super_attribute' => $superAttributeArray
     );
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();
```

this code works well and I can able to add the product in to cart. Tested the same in Database.

I want to map user id for the quote that was created.
products will be added only after loggging in.
When I add products with above code, customer_id field in 'sales_flat_quote' table is NULL. I want current logged in user id need to be set to this quote.

Can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
....
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();

$customer_id = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
$quote = $cart->getQuote();
$quote->setCustomerId($customer_id);
$quote->save();
```

Comment: its not working ..!! anyhow thanks for your support

Comment: Please explain more, is the customer_id field still blank?

Comment: Yes, after adding the code you have given, still customer_id field is empty.

Comment: Can you add some debugging code ....  Try to get the quote id before and after you save. `$quote->getId()` and the `$quote->setCustomerId()`